# want to show programming code in my webpage?

Tags: html, css

How to automatically format code of C++/or any language in html to show in webpage as it is displayed in TextEditor like brackets/sublime.want to highlight every code

example

[image]

Any Software to do this?

Comment: Use <pre></pre>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight source code in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70169/how-to-highlight-source-code-in-html)

Comment: @Gerard i want to change color for every code format/tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) or [prismjs](http://prismjs.com/).

These are popular javascript libraries that format your code like in an editor or IDE.

There are many more. Just google *html syntax highlighter*.

Comment: You can use comment of this kind of suggestions. Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: It's a suggestion but also an answer. It's straightforward, reasonable, explained and answers the question. This way the OP can highlight it as accepted. I don't see why I shouldn't post this as an answer.

Comment: @Wernerson +1 your answer is gr8. in highlightjs.org i have to define class for every single code. is there any software which can auto change the color or span?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understand what you mean but this may help: [highlightjs style guide](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style-guide.html#defining-a-theme)

Comment: @Wernerson One reason why you shouldn’t post an answer on this: the question is off-topic and answering encourages such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using the html `<code>` tag give you a good effect. [w3school on code tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_code.asp)

Thent you can try to find css to enrinch that.